# Error while calling a C# Webservice using AJAX - The result is a Dataset

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

This is my first experience with C# Web Service & AJAX ...
I would like to build a page like Facebook that will load the next set of records when we scroll down ...

I'm trying to use the code but it's **not** working at all ... 
Can you help me ?

**HTML Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="auto-load.aspx.cs" Inherits="auto_load" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>AEM - Comments</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var isLoading = false;
        var v_page_number = 1, v_page_size = 5;

        $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            loadComments();

            $(window).scroll(function () 
            {
                // Start loading when 200px from the bottom
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#main').height() - 200 && !isLoading) 
                {
                    loadComments();
                }
            });
        });

        function loadComments() 
        {
            isLoading = true;

            $.ajax(
            {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "auto-load.aspx/GetComment",
                    data: '{ "p_page_number" : ' + v_page_number + ', "p_page_size" : ' + v_page_size + ' }',
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: OnError
            });

        }


        // 
        function OnSuccess(data)
        {
            ShowXMLData(data);
        }


        // 
        function OnError(p_error)
        {

            if (p_error.status != 200) 
            { 
                $("#loading").html('Error:' + p_error.responseText + '<br /><br /><br /> Status: ' + p_error.status);
                //alert('Error:' + err.responseText + '  Status: ' + err.status); 
            }
        }


        function ShowXMLData(xml)
        {
            debugger;
            try
            {
                var v_comment = $(xml).find('Table');

                for (var i = 0; i < v_comment.length; i++) 
                {
                    var v_time_log_id  = v_comment[i]["time_log_id"];
                    var v_description  = v_comment[i]["description"];
                    var v_hours        = v_comment[i]["hours"];

                    // 
                    var v_comment = $('<div>');
                    var v_h2_description = $('<h2>');
                    var v_span_hours = $('<span>');

                    v_h2_description.html(v_description + ' / Id = ' + v_time_log_id + '</h2>');
                    v_span_hours.html('Number of hours: ' + v_hours + '</span>');


                    v_comment.append(v_h2_description);
                    v_comment.append(v_span_hours);
                    v_comment.append('</div>');

                    $('#feed').append(v_comment);

                });
            }

            catch(err)
            {
                var txt  = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
                    txt += "Error description: " + err.description + "\n\n";
                    txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";

                alert(txt);
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <div id="main">
        <h1>AEM - Comments</h1>
        <p>Showing Comments for AEM</p>
        <div id="feed">
        </div>
        <div id="loading">
            Loading Comments...
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**C# Code**

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

    using LibAEM;

    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Services;

    public partial class auto_load : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        [WebMethod]
        public string GetComment(int p_page_number, int p_page_size)
        {


            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Variable declaration
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string v_connection_string = LibNamtek.CConnection.GetDBConnection();   // Data Source=192.168.2.40;Initial Catalog=AEM;User ID=aem;Password=aem
            SqlConnection v_connection = new SqlConnection(v_connection_string);


            try
            {
                // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Main program
                // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                // Open Connection
                v_connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("pr_get_paging", v_connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_page_number", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@p_page_number"].Value = p_page_number;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_page_size", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@p_page_size"].Value = p_page_size;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet("TimeLog");
                da.Fill(ds);

                string v1 = ds.GetXml();
                return v1;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                if (v_connection != null)
                {
                    v_connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us a sample of the XML your web service is retrieving? It might be the case that your XML is wrapped in a "d" tag, but there's no way to tell without seeing the results of your AJAX call.

Comment: I have already posted a sample of the XML ... 
The variable v_comment contains the following value: b.fn.b.init[0]. What does it mean ?

EDIT:
If I store the result in a xml file (physical one) and i use the same code posted few hours ago, it works fine!